# Formatting Google Spreadsheet based on whether and where text is found

Tags: google-sheets

I have a number of students enrolled into groups. They are also split into two tutorials. I want to check whether all students enrolled and in which tutorial they enrolled. To this extent, I'd like to colour code the list of students. In the part above of the figure (up to row 5) I have the list of students into groups (tutorial 1 is row 1 and 2; tutorial 2 is row 4 and 5). In column A, rows 8 to 17 I have the list of students). What I would like is to search their names, so that if the student name is found in tutorial 1 (range A1:C2) then the background is green, if the name is found in tutorial 2 (range A4:C5) then the background is blue, and if the student is not found then the background is red. I have manually colour coded the list to show what I would like as the final result. Hope it makes sense!

[image: This is how my data is organised]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up three separate custom formulae across range A8:A17:

`=countif($1:$2,A8)` (Green)

`=countif($4:$5,A8)` (Blue)

`=countif($1:$5,A8)=0` (Red)

I set up an example sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SWGfxMKq6LZ98EgBpsiLqlzJJWedC9Xr0nuMKN3LdQQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!